Extracting Road Sections where Footpaths Exist in QGIS
I am trying to see if it's possible to extract the road network in QGIS, but only where there is a footpath along that section. This is so that we have a line representing footpaths but on the road centerline, whether or not there is a path on one or both sides. I'm not sure if this is possible or if there are any QGIS plugins/tools that may help. In the example below, the orange polygons represent road blocks. The pink is the road centerline and the black is the footpath. A process may involve finding footpaths within the road block, breaking the block up and then extracting that section of road centerline using a spatial intersection. The issue is some sections of footpath leave the road block which might just be a separate task. I've seen other maps that display footpaths in this way but not sure how they were created. 
